# How to give multiple lookup-attributes while querying cloudtrail events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudtrail

Is it possible to query cloudtrail with multiple lookup attributes

When I execute following

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=CreateTopic
```

It gives me list of events of type 'CreateTopic'

When I execute following

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=MyUserName
```

It gives me list of events related to user 'MyUserName'

However what I want is to query for all events of type 'CreateTopic' and related to user 'MyUserName'

I tried following but none of them works

```
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=CreateTopic,AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=MyUserName 
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=CreateTopic AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=MyUserName 
aws cloudtrail lookup-events --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=EventName,AttributeValue=CreateTopic --lookup-attributes AttributeKey=Username,AttributeValue=MyUserName
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation, `--lookup-attributes` only supports a one item list.

```
--lookup-attributes (list)

    Contains a list of lookup attributes. Currently the list can contain only one item.
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/lookup-events.html